# Chaining Async Methods in WCF Service

Tags: .net, wcf, asynchronous, async-await

I'm having a bit of trouble with the Async pattern and chaining methods in a WCF service.  The client is calling up to the WCF asyncronously, then the service method needs to asynchronously open a SOAP proxy and call some methods.

The problem is the nature of the Soap service is sequential, meaning i need one result, before i can get the next and return it to the calling WCF service. I am trying to use the Async pattern, but failing miserably here, because the sequential calls are bottlenecking the other async calls until it completes.

Is there any way to chain these Async SOAP methods, to prevent a bottleneck?

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
public class DetailsService : IDetailService
{

    public DetailEntity GetDetails(DetailEntity entity)
    {

        TransactionUtilities.GetTransactionDetails(entity);

         // return modified entity with details
        return entity;

    }

}

public static class TransactionUtilities
{
    static SoapClient SoapProxy { get; set; }

    public static void GetTransactionDetails(DetailEntity entity)
    {
        IAsyncResult ar = SoapProxy.BeginExecuteTransaction(loginToken, new AsyncCallback(OnExecuteTransactionEnd), null);
        // will this block other async calls?
        ar.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();
        string transactionId = SoapProxy.EndExecuteTransaction(ar);

        // another async call dependent on above transactionId
        IAsyncResult ar = SoapProxy.BeginGetTransactionResult(loginToken, processId, new AsyncCallback(OnTransactionResultEnd), null);
        ar.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();
        Row[] TransactionResult = SoapProxy.EndGetTransactionResult(ar);

        // do work with result
    }

            // call back methods, just haning out doing nothing
    static void OnExecuteTransactionEnd(IAsyncResult result) { }
    static void OnTransactionResultEnd(IAsyncResult result) { }

}
```

Comment: I'm quite confused by your question. First, you say that the calls have to be sequential. But you want to remove that bottleneck by chaining them? I don't understand how would that help. Second, your code is most certainly not asynchronous, because of all the `WaitOne()`.

Comment: The behavior is certainly not asyncronous, i know that. Then perhaps, it is how i am "Waiting" from the Asyncronous call. What can i do here, in place of the WaitOne() or Sleep() in .NET 4.0, that will not block other calls?